# How to get the master branch build numbers

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have recently started learning groovy. I am interested to know , is there a way to find get the build numbers of master branch. I have build numbers for different branches like hotfixes,patches , master , bug fix. I want to retrieve the build numbers of master of another job. Please help me on this scenario

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jenkins environment varaible to get the build number of master branch. I  am not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve. Can you elaborate your question by stating exactly what is it you want to acheve so that I can provide accurate answer.

Comment: I have a deploy_job and build_job. I want to write groovy in deploy_job to get the successful buildnumbers of master branch of build_job. I have a groovy script that gets the successful build numbers of build_job but my actual requirement is to get the successful build number of master branch. Please let me know if you need any more info